# HotChocolate quickstart example not working: no query showing up in Bana Cake Pop

Tags: c#, graphql, hotchocolate

I'm following the "getting started" example of HotChocolate located at https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/get-started.

When I access localhost:5207/graphql, I'm not seeing any queries under "Documents".

Here's what I tried without success:

- Use prerelease 12.4
- Used dotnet5 instead of dotnet6
- Used HotChocolate template (`dotnet new graphql` ) instead of adding code manually

Hints how to make the sample app work are welcome.

Code:

Program.cs

```cs
using Server;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services
.AddGraphQLServer()
.AddQueryType<Query>();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseRouting();
app.MapGraphQL();

app.Run();
```

Query.cs

```cs
namespace Server
{
    public class Query
    {
        public Book GetBook() =>
            new Book
            {
                Title = "C# in depth.",
                Author = new Author
                {
                    Name = "Jon Skeet"
                }
            };
    }
}
```

Book.cs and Author.cs:

```cs
namespace Server
{
    public class Book
    {
        public string Title { get; set; } = String.Empty;

        public Author Author { get; set; } = new Author();
    }

    public class Author
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: The Get Started currently contains old screenshots of the Banana Cake Pop IDE. You now have to open an new tab within this IDE and then you can select to view the Schema from the operations Drop Down: https://chillicream.com/docs/bananacakepop/getting-started

Comment: Indeed. That was it! I even tried clicking everywhere in the UI, but the only way to open a new tab seems to be through `CTRL+ALT+T`...?

Answer (score 0):

Quick starter package!

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services
.AddGraphQLServer()
.AddQueryType<Query>();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.MapGraphQL();
app.Run();

public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Query
{
    public IQueryable<Customer> GetCustomer() => new List<Customer>() { new Customer() { FirstName = "James", LastName = "Bond" }, new Customer() { FirstName = "Dr", LastName = "No" } }.AsQueryable();
}
```

query:

```
{
  customer {
    firstName
  }
}
```